# Is it possible to connect Django Oscar project with MongoDB?

Tags: django-oscar

I want to change the default database of my application built on top of a domain driven `Django Oscar` 
This is the default app settings for the database:

```
 DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

But I want to change it into MongoDB? 
How can I do this?

Comment: Related - https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/issues/1812#issuecomment-125776509

Comment: This seems to me like a question of whether Django itself supports noSQL databases, as there is nothing specific about Oscar that would have any impact on this. As far as I am aware, Django doesn't officially support such databases but there are third party connectors such as https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/ . You would need to try it to find out how far it gets you.